# Google Cloud Logging, streaming logs constantly stops after a few seconds

Tags: google-cloud-platform, logging

I'm looking at the Logs Explorer in the Google Cloud Logging console. I click "Stream Logs" in the top right and the panel below responds.. but then between ~4-18 seconds later (I tested with a stopwatch 5 or 6 times), the streaming stops and it gives me a message at the top "Streaming has paused. [Restart Streaming]".

[image]

I thought maybe I was scrolling with my mouse wheel and it was interrupting the stream or something, but I click Stream Logs (or Restart streaming) and then take my hands off keyboard and mouse and it almost instantly stops again.

Am I doing something wrong? Is this a bug?

Answer (score -2):

Based on Google documentation.

> As Logging writes the logs data, only logs that match the query are shown in the Query results pane. If a query isn't provided, then Logging shows the recently stored log entries. Logs continue streaming until you select the scroll bar on the logs panel. When streaming has stopped, a Restart streaming button is shown.

This is not a bug in the system. This event happens when you want to inspect something from the live stream, once you are done you can restart the live stream again and see the recent log entries.

You can also configure the [buffering and ordering](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/streaming-live-tailing#buffer) log entries so you can balance the trade-off between viewing the log entries as they are being written and viewing them in ascending order. Also, you can do this on [limit and quotas](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/streaming-live-tailing#limits_quotas).

Comment: As I said in my original post, I'm not selecting the scrollbar or scrolling my mouse wheel. I click Stream Logs or Restart Streaming and then take my hands off the keyboard and mouse and the streaming stops in about 6 seconds.

Comment: @KennyWyland can you provide a proof or video, it seems it doesn't happen to me until I move the scroll of the mouse wheel.

Comment: Check your Google Cloud Logging configuration if there are changes on buffering or quotas, link is already shared on the answer. You can try to configure, and observe if there are changes in its behavior.